# how to specify path of directory having package.json for sonar setup in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, npm, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project with below directory structure.

```
project
  -- abc/custom
     -- package.json
  -- test
     -- package.json
  -- jenkinsFile
```

My main project folder lacks package.json. Now I am trying to set up sonar in my jenkins file with below properties:-

```
    'sonar.working.directory':"${WORKSPACE}/abc/custom",
    'sonar.sources':"${WORKSPACE}/abc/custom",
    'sonar.projectBaseDir': "${WORKSPACE}/abc/custom",
    'sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath': "${WORKSPACE}/test/coverage/lcov.info", 
    'sonar.projectKey':'#KEY',
    'sonar.projectName':'#NAME',
    'sonar.projectVersion': '1.0',
    'sonar.sourceEncoding':'UTF-8',
    'sonar.login': #TOKEN
```

Whenever I try running the above with jenkins it fails with error:-

```
home/jenkins/workspace/PROJECT_NAME@tmp/durable/script.sh: line 4: node_modules/sonarqube-scanner/dist/bin/sonar-scanner: No such file or directory
```

It is not able to locate "sonarqube-scanner" that i have installed in node-modules of abc/custom folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `sonarqube-scanner` must be installed on the default location on Jenkins agent node where the workspace gets created and not on any other node or directory path.
2. Looking at the error, I can see 2 probabilities where the things might have gone wrong:

   a. The `sonarqube-scanner` path in Jenkins settings has been wrongly mentioned.

   b. `sonarqube-scanner` itself has not been installed on Jenkins agent node where this code is getting checked out.